# Angular 4 service behaviour change

Tags: angular, angular-services

I had my Angular 2 code logic written as new Service provider is generated when the Parent Component is re-instantiated each time. But, I guess there are some changes in Angular 4 that prevents destruction of Service provider and therefore, I'm getting the same set values repeated instead of default set.

By default, a service dependency provided in one component is visible to all of its child components and Angular injects the same service instance into all child components that ask for that service. But my question is what if ParentComponent is destroyed.

*Example:*
ParentA  /pages/parentA
 -ChildA /pages/parentA/childA
 -ChildB /pages/parentA/childB
ParentB  /pages/parentB

ParentA has service for sharing data among its children. Default value  `let x = 0`. When we move from ParentA -> ParentB the service should destroy as per Angular 2.

Again moving from ParentB -> ParentA service should be instantiated with default values since the scope of service is with ParentA only. This was the normal behaviour as per Angular 2.4.9. Which is not reflected in Angular 4.0.1 as of now.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour of Angular 4 ?

Comment: To me, the service and your component are two different classes, and as you said, there is a single instance of your service injected to your component and its childs (except for lazy-loaded modules, they have their own context and thus their own instance). 
Since to me the service and your component are two different classes, it makes sense to me that if your component instance is destroyed, your service is not, since it's linked to your module and not to the component.

I have no solution to give you though, but I hope this helps

Comment: By Component I meant Module only. ParentA and ParentB belong to different Modules, for which ParentA.module have Service defined in provider. When we navigate to ParentB module will be destroyed and therefore the service also. When we navigate to ParentA again new Service instance should be initiated. May be I'm wrong in defining the problem by the same logic was working in Angular 2.4.9 and not in Angular 4.0.1